# Get POST data from external in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a post form from external site request to my site like this

```
<form action="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="www.mysite.example/test">
 <input type="text" name="myInput" value="myValue">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then my controller config

```
angular.module('my-module')
    .config(function (pathServiceProvider, stateServiceProvider) {
        stateServiceProvider.state('my.state', {
            url: "/test",
            templateUrl: pathServiceProvider.generateTemplatePath("ocb-payments") + "/modules/test.html",
            controller: "PayUBKUStep1Controller",

        });
    })
    .controller('MyController',function(){
   // How can I get 'myValue' from form submit at here?
 })
```

Can I get 'myValue' in controller?

Answer (score 1):

This Form will send a request to the server indicated by the action attribute. Your client-side JavaScript (angularjs) is stored on a server, but it is *executed* in the client's computer when they load it. So the server application running at your site (Node.js, Java, Go, Python, etc.) will receive the POST request from the form.

Conventionally speaking, to get the data from the external form to your UI, you need to do the following:

- Receive the form on a server-side application
- Parse and persist the data on the server (in-memory or on-disk)
- In the UI, fetch the data from your server

You can improve this process a little bit (see: WebSocket), but the general idea is the same. You should implement a server-side application to process the form, and a client-side application to interact with the results.

[image]